# Call a function when console window is closed with "X"

Tags: c++, exit, terminate, abort, logfile

I'm having a problem with my console application in which I create a logfile to store different errors that occured while the programm was executed.

I'm writing all my error messages into a string buffer (a stringstream) and I'm passing a pointer of this buffer to all functions that use the buffer writing functions.

At the end I wanna check if the buffer is empty; if yes, then nothing happens and the main should return 0; if no, then the buffer should be written into a file.

There are no problems when the program is exited normally (in this case when main function returns 0) but how can I check the buffer when the application is closed with "X"? Can I catch an event?

I already tried std::setTerminate() but it only calls the handler function when the program is exited, not when I close it by pressing "X". Moreover, I really don't want to use SetConsoleCtrlHandler.

Comment: A console application has no idea aboit the X. There is no way to react on it. You may want to try catching SIGTERM and/or SIGPIPE. That's about the maximum of what a console application can do.

Comment: Hm.. okay, maybe I should try to catch a key combination and let it act as the actual "X" of the console application.. thanks!

Comment: A console application cannot catch key combinations.

Comment: It looks like you didn't soecify your platform. If it's Windows, disregard what I've just said and either use SetConsoleCtrlHandler, or do nothing. There are no other options.

Comment: Yep, it's windows.. ok, seems like I really have to use SetConsoleCtrlHandler.. thanks!